# Styling material ui table cells according to their values

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a material ui table and I would like to colour the different cells according to what value is displayed in them. The cells are populated with json data using map. For example if a cell has the value 1, I would like the colour to be yellow.

```
    {
      Name: "A Person",
      Attendence: [
        {
          date: "2019/12/01",
          attendence: 1
        },
        {
          date: "2019/12/02",
          attendence: 1
        },
        {
          date: "2019/12/03",
          attendence: 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {attendence.map(person => {
        return (
          <Table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                {person.Attendence.map(personAttendendance => {
                  return <th>{personAttendendance.date}</th>;
                })}
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>{person.Name}</td>
                {person.Attendence.map(personAttendendance => {
                  return <td>{personAttendendance.attendence}</td>;
                })}
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        );
      })}
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

That is what the table looks like. I tried

```
    if(value === 1){
      return(
        <TableCell style={{ background: "red" }}>{value}</TableCell>
      )

    } else {
      return(
        <TableCell style={{ background: "red" }}>{value}</TableCell>
      )
    }

  }
```

But that did not work . It just read the else and made everything red.

Comment: link to a codesandbox where this table is compiled https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-grass-sg5hr

Comment: Both your conditions have background: red

Comment: @AvcS mistake there. despite that mistake, it does not work

Comment: I just tried this if condition, it works as expected https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-moon-ilsci

Comment: @AvcS it works. My problem is that i i was not assigning value to anything. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `tbody` in test.js to:

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>{person.Name}</td>
      {person.Attendence.map(personAttendendance => {
          if(personAttendendance.attendence === 1){
             return <td style={{background: "red" }}>{personAttendendance.attendence}</td>;
          } else {
             return <td style={{background: "blue" }}>{personAttendendance.attendence}</td>;
          }                  
      })}
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

or

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>{person.Name}</td>
      {person.Attendence.map(personAttendendance => {
          return <td style={{background: personAttendendance.attendence === 1 ? "red" : "blue"}}>{personAttendendance.attendence}</td>;                
      })}
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Which ever suits you best.

Link to fork [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-montalcini-9g7li?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). (using the second example)